# Error when adding Recaptcha in office 365

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sharepoint, recaptcha, office365

I have tried my best to create a validation method validate the input of recaptcha. But I failed during this process.

I have the following code in the Validator.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify");
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

When I uploaded this to sharepoint online site I am getting the following error.

```
Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

I checked in the MSDN and it Says for sandbox solutions:
". As another example, it is prohibited to use the Create method of the HTTPWebRequest class to create a connection to other external websites."

Please provide me a solution to overcome this. How Can I create recaptcha to use in office 365.
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how big is the scope of your application but since the recaptcha has to be verified via server side code, the only option I can think of is to create a provider hosted app (or auto hosted if it suits) instead of a sandbox solution. The other option is to consider using other alternative solutions instead of recaptcha.

Comment: @Jomit: thanks. I want to deploy in to sharepoint online. I have to include this in to my subscription web part. since i cant achieve this using server side code i like know what are the alternative solutions to this.thanks again